# Index out bound error when I try doing a binary search through the array

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to create a program that does a binary search of array of randomly generated doubles and when I try to run the code, I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 9999 out of bounds for length 9999
    at Search.binarySearch(Search.java:34)
    at Search.main(Search.java:17)
```

I tried changing the array size and making it smaller and bigger, but I always get a error. I don't know what less I can do. Here is the code.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

class Search{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double [] array2  = new double [9999];  
        for(int i = 0; i <array2.length;i++){   
            array[i] = (double) (Math.random() * 9999); 
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(binarySearch(array, new Random().nextDouble(9999)));
    }

    public static int binarySearch(double [] array, double find){
        int first = 0;
        int last = array.length;
        int mid = (first + last ) / 2;
        while(first <= last){
            if(array[mid] < last){
                first = mid +1;
            }else if(array[mid] == find){
                return mid;
            }else{
                last = mid -1;
            }
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
        }
        if(first > last){
            return -1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How it is supposed to work that it takes the array of doubles and a random number to find if the number is in the array, if it is returns the index, if its not in the array, it returns -1. I have a linear search method that works but for some reason this won't work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Array index out of bound means you are trying to access the array element which is not within the array.

In Java `array.length` gives you the size of an array.

But elements of an array are identified by the `index` and `index` value starts from `0`.

Which means that first element of an array has the `index =  0` and the last element has the `index = array.length(size) - 1`.


In your code of binary search, you are taking `int last = array.lenght` which is wrong.

It should be `int last = array.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] arr = new double[9999];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = random.nextDouble() * 9_999;

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(binarySearch(arr, random.nextDouble() * 9_999));
}

public static int binarySearch(double[] arr, double find) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = arr.length - 1;

    while (lo + 1 < hi) {
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        int res = Double.compare(find, arr[mid]);

        if (res == 0)
            return mid;
        if (res < 0)
            hi = mid;
        else
            lo = mid;
    }

    if (Double.compare(find, arr[lo]) == 0)
        return lo;
    if (Double.compare(find, arr[hi]) == 0)
        return hi;

    return -1;
}
```